# HTML link a una pagina web externa que no funciona

Tags: html5, enlace

Estoy creando una pagina web, y se apenas nada de HTML.
Pretendo insertar un link a una pagina web externa. El codigo que he insertado es:

```
 <li><a href=”https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32511785/” target=”_blank”>Multiple pathways coordinate assembly of human mitochondrial complex IV and stabilization of respiratory supercomplexes</a></li>
```

Sin embargo en la barra de direcciones de Chrome me sale lo siguiente:

file:///F:/DIW_DAW/DIW_01/Tarea_DIW/Prototipo/%E2%80%9Dhttps://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32511785/%E2%80%9D

El navegador entiende que quiero navegar dentro de mi sistema de ficheros en lugar de por la web. Si alguien me puede indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Cambia las comillas (parece que tengan formato) por unas comillas normales

Comment: Cierto. Eran comillas raras. Pero no ha solucionado el problema. El link me abre una nueva ventana en que añade la dirección a la apunto a la dirección que tiene el archivo html en mi directorio.

Comment: Ponle estas comillas ''

Comment: O sea, te sigue pasando lo mismo, no?  Pues si has cambiado las comillas no tiene sentido.  Mira, aquí es con las comillas malas: https://jsfiddle.net/ryz0wcs4/  (si haces click en el enlace verás que también lo hace mal).  En cambio, con las comillas arregladas parece ir bien:  https://jsfiddle.net/dmjnzkp5/  (recuerda que las comillas debes arreglarlas tanto en el enlace como en el _blank).

Comment: Exacto ese es problema. Las cambié antes pero no recargué la página. Ahora va perfecto. Gracias